# get bounding box coordinated from object detection api after eval

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I used Object Detection API from Tensorflow to train my model. The eval script also worked fine.

However, I want to get the coordinates of the bounding box in eval images. Is that possible to do so in eval script? How can I do it?

I used [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/eval.py).

Answer (score 0):

A few examples (how many is set by `num_visualizations` in the config file) are shown on TensorBoard.

If you want more than that, I suggest to export the model and use inference.
See the [TF OD tutorial notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) for how to use an exported model for inference and visualizing results.

Comment: While the eval script gets the bounding box coordinates, can I not get those coordinates? Why do I have to export the image? I need to do some calculations based on this bounding box coordinates.

Comment: I did not understand the first question. Regarding the second - it would be easier to use inference, what you practically want. Regarding the third - you can access them using `output_dict['detection_boxes']` in the tutorial I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424348/tensorflow-object-detection-api-multiple-objects-coordinates/57263771#57263771).
Although this does not have any relation with the `eval.py` script, it gets the job done. If you specify a directory consisting of the test images, you can get the bounding box coordinates of all the detected objects using the model you have trained.